# Prove Parallelogram Area Is Twice Triangle Area

Tags: geometry, triangles

I thought this would be easy but I can't seem to find the answer.

Edit: I did my best to draw the diagram:

[image: triangle diagram]

$\overline{EC}=\frac{1}{3} \overline{AC}, \overline{AF}=\frac{1}{3} \overline{AB}, \overline{BD}=\frac{1}{3} \overline{BC}$

I drew a line parallel to $\overline{BE}$ through $R$. I called the intersection of that line and $\overline{AB}$ point $M$. I drew a line parallel to $\overline{AD}$ through $B$, and called the intersection of that line and my previous line $G$. Then I want to prove $BGRP = 2\triangle PRQ$. This is for the ultimate goal of solving the $1/7$ area triangle problem. In addition I need to prove $\triangle BGM = \triangle ARM$, and to prove that I think I need to prove $M$ is the midpoint. I think I'm close with similar triangles $\triangle ARM$ and $\triangle APB$ but I can't get the relationship. Thanks if you managed to read all this.

Edit: A full proof is given [here](http://mathafou.free.fr/pbw_en/pb420.html), I just need someone to clarify the dialations and transformations.

Comment: $DPR$ are collinear, right? So, what's $BDRP$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oops, I didn't realize $D$ was already used. I've changed it to $G$

Comment: OK, so several of the important objects do not appear in the diagram. Pity.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I could try out my MS paint skills :P

Comment: It is not exactly clear where the point $G$ is. Can you show it in your diagram?

Comment: @TanmayInamdar I've made a diagram

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routh's_theorem ,         


http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-seventh_area_triangle

Comment: @Sawarnik I am aware of Routh's theorem but I did not want to use it.

Comment: @qwr You can reprove it in your way. But the second Wiki link, i gave you mentions that a number of proofs have been found. You can see those references.

Comment: @Sawarnik none of the links work except for one, and the one that does work the java applet doesn't load for me.

Comment: What are you actually trying to prove? I don't see how the diagram has anything to do with the title.

Comment: @user2357112 Did you read my details? They explicitly tell what I need to prove.

Comment: Your question needs more of a description of the problem. You jump right into diagrams and constructions and only vaguely describe the goal halfway through ("solving the 1/7 area triangle problem"). Unless the reader is already familiar with the problem, it's difficult to tell what's going on.

Comment: It is one of the most challenging geometry questions I have ever seen

Answer (score 1):

In the barycentric coordinates associated with $\triangle ABC$, we have
$$ P = [1,4,2] \qquad\text{and}\qquad Q = [2,1,4] $$
Of course I solved a linear system to get this, but it's easy to check after the fact: $[1,4,2]$ is on the line joining $A[1,0,0]$ and $D[0,2,1]$ (since it's $[1,0,0] + 2[0,2,1]$) and on the line joining $B[0,1,0]$ and $E[1,0,2]$ (since it's $4[0,1,0]+[1,0,2]$), so it must be $P$.  Then we get the coordinates of $Q$ by symmetry.

Thus $P$ is the midpoint of $BQ$.  (Take $B = [0,7,0]$.)

Comment: I thought barycentric coordinates had fraction values for points inside the triangle?

Comment: If you like, you can scale everything I wrote so that each point's coordinates add up to 1: $P=[\frac17,\frac47,\frac27]$, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Proving $\triangle BGM ~ \triangle ARM$ is easy. 
$\angle GMB = \angle AMR$ because they are vertically opposite angles. 
$\angle GBM = \angle MAR$ because line $BG$ is parallel to line $AR$, and the angles are corresponding angles made by intercept $GR$. 
For proving $BGRP=2PRQ$, you need to show $BP=PQ$ which is not clear to me using this information.

Comment: The triangles are similar, but to prove they're equal you need to prove $M$ is the midpoint of $AB$?

Comment: I thought you were referring to the angles, it seems you were talking about the triangles. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

All we need is to prove $\overline{BP} = \overline{PQ} $

Comment: Can you add detail? As in, how you would prove that, because that's a large part of solving the problem.

Comment: I would you like to.. But not yet.